# WCF Service Hosted in a Managed Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config

I followed this(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) link and created a service and and a service host.
I added a webform client project to the solution. In order to check that my service is receiving a request I added a log in the service. 
I selected my host and client to run at the same time by setting multiple start up project.
But I am having a problem making a communication between my service and client.Am i missing something in the configuration? i don't see exception at all(even though I selected CLR and JSRuntime exception, and managed debugging assistance ).

Here is my service configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <client/>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="meta">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator" behaviorConfiguration="meta" >
            <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator" name="basic"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <!--<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="Ws"  />-->
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress = "http://IP/InboundMessage.Service/"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator"/>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```

Service Host:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="meta">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <diagnostics performanceCounters="ServiceOnly" />
        <services>
          <service name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator" behaviorConfiguration="meta">
            <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator" name="basic"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <!--<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
          </service>
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.web>
        <compilation
            debug="true" >
        </compilation>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

a windowform Client configuration:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
      </configSections>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"></compilation>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service  behaviorConfiguration="meta" name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator">
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://IP/InboundMessage.Service/"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>    
            <binding name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator"/> 
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="meta">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>     
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

EDIT:
Used Tim's comment to install the service but I am having problem installing it.
I opened another question thanks Tim i am having problem installing the service on my local machine. I opened another question :[Unable to install service using sc command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416910/unable-to-install-service-using-sc-command)

Answer (score 0):

A few of things come to mind.

First (I'm not 100% sure, but this is based on my experiences) you can't run a Windows Service as a Windows Service through Visual Studio.  You need to build the project and then install it, as directed on the page you linked to.

Secondly, you only need two configuration files, not three - one for the Windows Service (which is where the configuration for the service goes) and one for the client.  I'm not sure what role you have (or believe you have) for the service host config file.

Third, your client config has entries for a service in the `<system.serviceModel>` section - you only need those if your client is also hosting a service, which doesn't appear to be the case in the question you've asked.  You should remove the `<services>` section and add a `<client>` section, like this:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://IP/InboundMessage.Service" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="InboundMessage.Service.Operator" 
            contract="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator" />
</client>
```

Note that I used the `bindingConfiguration` attribute above - without that, your client will use the default `basicHttpBinding` (which in your case won't matter because you didn't set anything other than the name, but if you had set non-default values you would want to tell the client which binding configuration to use).

In reality the simplest way (to get started) would be to build the Windows Service, install it and start it, and then add a service reference to it in your client (WinForm) application.  That will generate everything you need and you can take a look at the config file to see the settings you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . when you say"(which in your case won't matter because you didn't set anything other than the name, " can you elaborate more where you think i set the name? is it in the service? another thing since i removed <services> tag from client do I need to remove the <behaviors> tag too?

Comment: @HXD - Sorry, I wasn't very clear in that part of the answer.  What I meant was you have a `basicHttpBinding` configuration defined in the config file, named "InboundMessage.Service.Operator".  You don't referenced that binding configuration in the endpoint, so it will not be used.  Since you didn't specify any values for the "InboundMessage.Service.Operator" binding configuration, it won't matter.  Had you specified a bigger messages size limit, for example, then it would matter.  And yes, you can remove the `<behaviors>` tag as well.

Comment: thanks Tim i am having problem installing the service on my local machine. I opened another question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416910/unable-to-install-service-using-sc-command