# Unable to install service using sc command

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, cmd, installation

I have my service under this folder path

C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\TestServices\TestServices\InboundMessage.ServiceHost\bin\Debug  --- > here is were all my dlls and .exe is

I use this command to install to my local box

sc create "Receiver Services" binPath= "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\TestServices\TestServices\InboundMessage.ServiceHost\InboundMessage.ServiceHost.exe" displayname= "*Receiver Services"

sc description "Receiver Services" "Receiver Services."

sc delete "Receiver Services" "Receiver Services."

I opened my cmd(c:\windows\System32) and execute the above command.

the service is installed but i am not able to start it because it throw the error: Windows couldn't start the service on local machine Error 2:the system couldn't find the file specified.

**EDIT:**
I right click and check the property of the service installed to check the path. and it matches the one I put in the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is one spelling error. Now my service is up and running.

Comment: remember to mark the question as answered, otherwise it still appears on the list. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InstallUtil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Execute the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 with high privileges and then run:

`installutil yourWithAWindowsService.exe`

Comment: I am getting the same error that's why I switch to the above command.